# Changing symbol names after linking

Tags: c, symbols

Is it possible to take a static object and rename symbols in such a way that it wouldn't break function calls?

For example if we have a static object containing two functions:

```
void A()
{
  //Do stuff
}
```

and

```
void B()
{
  A();
}
```

Assuming these are externally declared C functions then the .so would contain two symbols - A and B. Is there a way to rename A -> funcA and B -> funcB?

(The second part of the question relating to function calls is based upon my naivety with respect to linking, if you simply change the name will the function calls break or not?)

P.S. Platform is linux, probably compiled with gcc, but if there's a cross compiler way then I'd be glad for it!

Comment: Why can't you just rename them to what you want before compiling the code?

Comment: Because the real life situation isn't quite as clean cut as the example - I want to rename EVERY symbol within a library (well those that I've coded). So that would be a hell of a lot of search and replace. This search and replace would end up obfuscating the code which I do not want (however I want to be able to link them in a strange way for my own reasons).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the man page on objcopy utility, in particular the --redefine-syms option.